# disable connection to a website with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, connection

Is it possible to disable the internet of a tab in a browser using javascript and cut the connection to a server? Like disabling the outgoing connections in firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way you can simulate network errors is with [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Recovering_failed_requests), by intercepting requests and hijacking the response with your own content:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(
  event.request.url.matches(BLOCK) ? Response.error() : fetch(event.request)
));
```

Another viable approach, perhaps one that better conveys what is it that your actually attempting to accomplish, is by adding appropriate [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) directives. You could achieve this with your server, by adding them through response headers, statically in your HTML markup or by dynamically adding elements to the DOM.